# Fast way of graphing db statistics onto a webpage

Tags: mysql, database, charts, highcharts, gwt-highcharts

I currently have a MySQL database with a bunch of statistics about my data I record each day, a row/per day.   These are numeric statistics, and I'm wondering what's the fastest way to retrieve the data and graph it as a line chart on a webpage?

I'm familiar with Java/Hibernate, but I'm open to any quick way to quickly retrieve the data and plop it onto a webpage.  This can even been a product I sign up for, and I send them data through an API, and they give me back graphs for me (kinda like Excel almost).

In terms of displaying the charts I heard good things about

http://www.highcharts.com/products/highstock

if I implement myself.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

you might wanna check out this interactive chart library:

http://datavisualizationsoftwarelab.com

pst. more goodies coming very soon:

[image]

also, here is interactive demo:

```
var settings = {
    series: [{
        type: "columns",
        style: {
            fillColor: "LimeGreen",
        }
    }],
    container: document.getElementById("timechart")
};

var tc = new TimeChart(settings);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vt2pu/)